# Issues with verifying user against database and redirection to another html page

Tags: php, mysql

Somehow my Login.php below throws error on line $result but my connection is successful.

Also how can i redirect to progress.html page but hold on to the username to update user's progress against objectives.

note that i am new to coding and grab various codes from here, so far thank you all.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
include ('connection.php');

$conn = OpenCon();

echo "Connected Successfully";

$username = $_POST['user']; 
$password = $_POST['pswd']; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE username = '$username' AND pswd = 
SHA2(CONCAT('$password','$username'),512)";


$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($numrows = 1) { echo "welcome" ;}
else { echo "wrong username or password"; }


CloseCon($conn);
?>

error message : 
array(3) { ["user"]=> string(6) 
"atilla" ["pswd"]=> string(3) 
"ATI" ["remember"]=> string(2) "on" } 

Connected Successfully Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /storage/ssd2/778/10859778/public_html/Login.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd2/778/10859778/public_html/Login.php on line 16
```

Comment: error message : array(3) { ["user"]=> string(6) "atilla" ["pswd"]=> string(3) "ATI" ["remember"]=> string(2) "on" } Connected Successfully
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /storage/ssd2/778/10859778/public_html/Login.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd2/778/10859778/public_html/Login.php on line 16

Comment: The error message tells you where the error is. Are you using mysql or mysqli (mysql has been deprecated thus not available).

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP version 7.x, so it don't support mysql. You should use mysqli or PDO. Please view info about mysql_query in [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Also, You can session to save current user. If you want to redirect and , you can use:

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

Comment: thank you, i get this error when replace welcome with header.   I assume header needs to be called before but not sure how. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd2/778/10859778/public_html/Login.php:2) in /storage/ssd2/778/10859778/public_html/Login.php on line 21

Comment: Probaby, you called echo before header function. You should add exit(), die() after header.